# Threads não executam - Python

Tags: python, thread

Preciso alocar diversas threads para processarem um determinado array de dados. Porém independentemente do número de threads que aloco, uma delas sempre fica sem executar (geralmente a primeira). Segue trecho de código:

```
def iniciaThreads(self, tamanho, funcao):
    _passo = int( (tamanho/self.NUM_THREADS) )
    _resto = tamanho%self.NUM_THREADS

    _process = None

    _limites = []
    _limites.append(0)
    _limites.append(_passo-1)

    for i in range(self.NUM_THREADS-1):
        _process =  threading.Thread(target=funcao, name=str(i), args=[_limites])
        _process.start()
        self.threads.append(_process)
        _limites[0] += _passo
        _limites[1] += _passo

    _limites[1] += _resto
    _process =  threading.Thread(target=funcao, name=str(self.NUM_THREADS), args=[_limites])
    _process.start()
    self.threads.append(_process)

def joinThreads(self):
    for i in self.threads:
        i.join()
```

Função executada pelas threads:

```
def processaDescricao(limites):
   print("INICIADA: " + str(limites[0])+" - "+str(limites[1]))
   for i in range(limites[0], limites[1]+1):
       for j in palavras_chave:
           requisicoes[i].eliminaPalavra(j)
       requisicoes[i].eliminaCaracteresEspeciais()
```

Comment: Quem seta o valor de `self.NUM_THREADS`?

Comment: self.NUM_THREADS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

Comment: Cara, esse código isolado parece estar funcionando normalmente. https://repl.it/@MaxFratane/OblongMarvelousPublishers

Comment: Poisé, mas a primeira thread não executa, inicia mas não executa. Parece que é finalizada quando as demais iniciam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente a thread é iniciada, e sua surpresa vem do fato de que a sua variável `_limites`  vai ser o *mesmo* objeto dentro de cada thread. 
Você está passando uma lista para uma thread - as outras threads vão ver a mesma lista. Quando os valores forem atualizados na thread principal, as workers vão ver os valores atualizados.

Se quiser mesmo usar uma lista para isso, passe uma cópia da mesma:

```py
from copy import copy
...
    _process =  threading.Thread(target=funcao, name=str(self.NUM_THREADS), args=[copy(_limites)])
```

Ou simplesment, já que são só dois valores, expanda a sequência "limites", de forma que cada item vire um parâmetro diferente:

```
    _process =  threading.Thread(target=funcao, name=str(self.NUM_THREADS), args=[*_limites])

...

def processaDescricao(inicio, fim):
   print("INICIADA: " + str(limites[0])+" - "+str(limites[1]))
   for i in range(limites[0], limites[1]+1):
       for j in palavras_chave:
           requisicoes[i].eliminaPalavra(j)
       requisicoes[i].eliminaCaracteresEspeciais()
```

Algumas notas não relacionadas com seu problema principal:
Você provavelmente vai ter um erro no tamanho da sua fatia aí  - o comportamento
padrão do Python, de fatias fechadas no início e abertas no final (o elemento na posição final não é incluido na fatia), resolve quase todos os problemas desse tipo, sem necessidade de ficar subtraindo ou aumentando "1" aos índices de inicio e final de fatias.

Em particular, essa linha aqui: `_limites.append(_passo-1)`  deveria ser só `_limites.append(_passo)`  - e você vai ter menos dor de cabeça.

Segundo: Python tem várias formas de interpolar valores em strings, e todas elas mais práticas do que fechar um trecho da string e usar `+` para concatenar o valor desejado.
A recomendação em Python moderno é usar as f-strings que podem expandir expressões de código dentro de  `{  }` dentro da string.

Ou seja:

```
 print("INICIADA: " + str(limites[0])+" - "+str(limites[1]))
```

fica

```
 print(f"INICIADA: {limites[0]} - {limites[1]}")
```

E por fim, o uso de "_" como prefixo de nomes de variáveis é recomendado para indicar que variáveis, atributos e métodos são de uso privado do implementador daquele código. Mas nem isso muda nada na forma como o Python trata essas variáveis, nem faz sentido para variáveis locais (que já são  de acesso restrito por natureza). Elas só fazem atrapalhar a leitura do codigo, com símbolos que fazem o cérebro parar pra pensar "que esse  `_` tá fazendo aí". (é uma parada pequena e imperceptível conscientemente, mas repetida pra cada nome de variável que você vê no seu programa enquanto estiver mexendo no código - o saldo final é um programador mais cansado)